# How to test mouse clientY in React testing (JEST)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
useEffect(() => {
    const maybeHandler = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      menuData.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.hasActiveDropdown && event.clientY > 50) {
          handleCloseDropDown();
          // handleDropDown('0');
        }
      });
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', maybeHandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', maybeHandler);
  }, [handleCloseDropDown, menuData]);
```

I am used this useEffect to handle mulltip dropdowns in navbar component,
navbar has fix height 50px so my logic is whenver use click outside the navbar the drop downs all are close.

I am unadble to test in JEST this clientY propery

Answer (score 0):

For my project I basically had a function that detected when the scroll happens *This Project Was In React TypeScript*

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', onScroll);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart);        
window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
```

and it calls back to onScroll

```
    function onScroll(e:any)   {
        if(Math.abs(e.deltaY) <= 35 || Scrolled) return;
        Scrolled = true;
        //console.log(e.deltaY);
        let direction = e.deltaY;
        //console.log(page);

        if(direction > 0) page++;
        if(direction < 0) page--;

        //console.log(page);

        if(page <= 0) page = (0);
        if(page >= (pagesRef.current.length-1)) page = (pagesRef.current.length-1);

        pagesRef.current[page].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        setTimeout(()=>{Scrolled=false},800);
    }
```

and for touch / mobile devices

```
    function handleTouchStart(evt:any) {
        const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
        xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
        yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
    };                                                
                                                                             
    function handleTouchMove(evt:any) {
        if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
            return;
        }
    
        var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
        var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;
    
        var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
        var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                             
        if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
            if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
                /* right swipe */ 
            } else {
                /* left swipe */
            }                       
        } else {
            if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
                page++;
            } else { 
                page--;
            }                                                                 
        }

        if(page <= 0) page = (0);
        if(page >= (pagesRef.current.length-1)) page = (pagesRef.current.length-1);

        pagesRef.current[page].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});

        /* reset values */
        xDown = null;
        yDown = null;                                             
    };
```

Hope this can help